# How is comparison working for PriorityQueue

Tags: java, comparison, priority-queue

I am referring to the code listed on this blog: https://strstr.io/Leetcode1054-Distant-Barcodes/

I am copying this code here

```
class Solution {
    public int[] rearrangeBarcodes(int[] barcodes) {
        if(barcodes == null || barcodes.length == 0)
            return new int[0];
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i: barcodes)
            map.put(i, map.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
        PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(
        (a,b)->b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0?a.getKey() - b.getKey(): b.getValue() - a.getValue());
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry:map.entrySet())
            pq.offer(entry);
        int[] res = new int[barcodes.length];
        int i = 0;
        while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
            int k = 2;
            List<Map.Entry> tempList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>();
            while(k > 0 && !pq.isEmpty()) {
                Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> head = pq.poll();
                head.setValue(head.getValue() - 1);
                res[i++] = head.getKey();
                tempList.add(head);
                k--;
            }
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e: tempList) {
                if(e.getValue() > 0) 
                    pq.add(e);
            }
            if(pq.isEmpty())
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The code which i am trying to understand is here

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(
        (a,b)->b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0?a.getKey() - b.getKey(): b.getValue() - a.getValue());
```

What i am getting out of this code is that `PriorityQueue` is being constructed with a `Comparator`. Values `a` and `b` are two values which are being compared. Now

1. Why the difference between `a` and `b` being compared to 0? Why not `<` or `>` to each other?
2. In case if ternary operation, why the return value is either `key` or `value`? This bit is confusing me the most.

Comment: (1) Did you read the contract for `Comparator`? (2) This is a very complicated way of saying `comparingInt(Entry::getValue).thenComparingInt(Entry::getKey)`..

Comment: contract tells that it should return `-1`, `0` or `1` if the first value is less, equal or bigger. so why this is being compared to `0` only. why it's not deciding if it's less or bigger? (2) can you explain it a little bit

Comment: Because comparing to exactly 0 means "is equal to", in which case it uses a tiebreaker.

Answer (score 2):

`(a,b)->b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0?a.getKey() - b.getKey(): b.getValue() - a.getValue()` is using a lambda to define a Comparator that does the following:
`b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0?`
When compareTo is invoked, first check if `a.getValue()` is the same as `b.getValue()`.
If it is the same, then return `a.getKey() - b.getKey()`
Otherwise, return `b.getValue() - a.getValue()`

What does this mean in the context of your problem? Let's see. First, recall that Java's PriorityQueue acts as a min-heap according to the Comparator that it is given; that is, the first element pulled out is the one such that elem.[compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)(other) returns -1 or 0 for ANY other element within the PriorityQueue. We can use this to determine which elements will be the first ones to be extracted from the PriorityQueue.
There are a few cases here:

- `a.getValue() == b.getValue()`: We evaluate `a.getKey() - b.getKey()`

  - `a.getKey() == b.getKey()`
  - In this case, we return 0.
  - `a.getKey() > b.getKey()`
  - In this case, we return 1.
  - `a.getKey() < b.getKey()`
  - In this case, we return -1.
  - **This branch is like a regular comparator on getKey(), which means a comparator on the barcode number**
- 'a.getValue() != b.getValue()`: We evaluate`b.getValue() - a.getValue()`

  - `a.getValue() > b.getValue()`
  - In this case, we return -1.
  - `a.getValue() < b.getValue()`
  - In this case, we return 1.
  - **This branch is like a reversed comparator on getValue(), which means a reversed comparator on barcode frequency**

When we put it all together, what does it all mean? The expression `(a,b)->b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0?a.getKey() - b.getKey(): b.getValue() - a.getValue()` uses a lambda function to define a comparator such that *elements removed from the PriorityQueue will be extracted in order from* **highest** *to* **lowest** *barcode frequency. If the barcode frequency for any two barcodes is the* **same**, *those barcodes will be ordered relative to each other in order from* **lowest** *to* **highest** *barcode number.*

If the following "barcode":"barcode frequency" pairs were inside the PriorityQueue

> 1:2
>   2:4
>   3:2
>   4:1

they would be extracted in the following order:

> 2:4, 1:2, 3:2, 4:1

Also, to clarify why they are comparing `a` and `b` to 0, they are not. Instead, they are comparing `b.getValue()-a.getValue() == 0`. Adding `a.getValue()` to both sides of the equation, we get `b.getValue() == a.getValue()`. Essentially, they are testing whether these values are equal, not whether the values are 0.